# Raphael Transform - Scale then Rotation, skew effect

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

Here is a jsfiddle of a problem I am encountering:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tw4Qh/1/

Given this html:

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

and this js (all demonstrated in jsfiddle):

```js
var paper = Raphael('box', 300, 300);
var center = { x:150, y:150 }, size = { x:10, y:10 };
var look = { stroke:'#000000', 'stroke-width':1,
    fill:'#888888', opacity:1, 'stroke-opacity':0.9,
    'fill-opacity': 0.7, 'stroke-dasharray': '- '
};
var path = paper.path('').attr(look);

function reset() {
    // reset to small square
    path.attr({ path:[
        [ 'M', center.x - size.x, center.y - size.y ],
        [ 'L', center.x + size.x, center.y - size.y ],
        [ 'L', center.x + size.x, center.y + size.y ],
        [ 'L', center.x - size.x, center.y + size.y ],
        [ 'z' ]
    ] }).transform([]);
    console.log(path._.transform);
}

function add_state_one() {
    // move down and left slightly and scale up
    path.transform(path._.transform.concat([
        [ 'T', -50, 10 ],
        [ 'S', 2.5, 7.5 ]
    ]));
    console.log(path._.transform);
}

function add_state_two() {
    // use bounding box center
    var bb = path.getBBox(),
        center = { x:(bb.x + bb.x2)/2, y:(bb.y + bb.y2)/2 };
    path.transform(path._.transform.concat([
        [ 'R', 30, center.x, center.y ],
        [ 'S', 0.8, 0.7, center.x, center.y ]
    ]));
    console.log(path._.transform);
}

function add_state_three() {
    // use original center
    path.transform(path._.transform.concat([
        [ 'R', 45, center.x, center.y ],
        [ 'S', 0.7, 0.5, center.x, center.y ]
    ]));
    console.log(path._.transform);
}

// buttons
var blook = { 'stroke-dasharray':'', stroke:'transparent' };
var btn = {
    rst:paper.path([ [ 'M', 0, 0 ], [ 'L', 10, 0 ],
               [ 'L', 10, 10 ], [ 'L', 0, 10 ], [ 'z' ] ])
        .attr(look).attr(blook).click(reset),
    st1:paper.path([ [ 'M', 20, 0 ], [ 'L', 30, 0 ],
            [ 'L', 30, 10 ], [ 'L', 20, 10 ], [ 'z' ] ])
        .attr(look).attr(blook).attr({ fill:'#0000ff' })
        .click(add_state_one),
    st2:paper.path([ [ 'M', 40, 0 ], [ 'L', 50, 0 ],
            [ 'L', 50, 10 ], [ 'L', 40, 10 ], [ 'z' ] ])
        .attr(look).attr(blook).attr({ fill:'#ff0000' })
        .click(add_state_two),
    st3:paper.path([ [ 'M', 60, 0 ], [ 'L', 70, 0 ],
            [ 'L', 70, 10 ], [ 'L', 60, 10 ], [ 'z' ] ])
        .attr(look).attr(blook).attr({ fill:'#00ff00' })
        .click(add_state_three)
};

// click grey
reset();
```

Basically I need to apply a scale, then apply a rotation, without the rotation being affected by the scale.

Imagine you have a square. Now you apply a scale to it, such that it is a tall rectangle. Now you want to rotate this resulting rectangle in such a way that it remains a rectangle, with right angled corners, but is at a 45 degree angle. We are trying to achieve a rectangle that is balancing on one corner, leaning at a 45 degree angle. Instead, as demonstrated in the jsfiddle, when I apply a scale (resulting in a rectangle), then a rotate (to tilt it on a corner), I instead wind up with a skewed rectangle (or weird looking diamond).

I am sure some body knows how to achieve this. Ultimately I plan on adding multiple different transforms (translations, rotations, and scales), from multiple points of origin, but I do not want this skewing effect to happen. Just trying to figure this out. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing your point, just apply add_state_three on its own, as that does the scale and rotation without skewing it ?

Comment: By that, I also mean if you want to combine multiple transforms, you may be better off calculating the correct total transform and applying just once.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after some time trying to find where exactly it came from, i figured out what causes it is the irregular scale. Whenever your x and y axis are scaled differently, thats gonna happen.

What i did to get around it was to undo the irregular scaling before rotation, then redo it. To undo it, you should re-scale it by the inverses of the original scales. In your example, to get the state 2 working, you could do:

```
function add_state_two() {
    // use bounding box center
    var bb = path.getBBox(),
        center = { x:(bb.x + bb.x2)/2, y:(bb.y + bb.y2)/2 };
    path.transform(path._.transform.concat([
        [ 'S', 1/2.5, 1/7.5, center.x, center.y ],
        [ 'R', 30, center.x, center.y ],
        [ 'S', 2.5*0.8, 7.5*0.7, center.x, center.y ]
    ]));
    console.log(path._.transform);
}
```

First i made it go back to the original, 1:1 scale. Then rotated it, then rescaled it. Note i multiplied the original values, on the second scale, by the new ones, so you dont have two separate scales. That should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tw4Qh/2/